# Logical OR operators throws a syntax error here in JS - where am I going wrong?

Tags: javascript

Logical OR operators throws a syntax error here in JS - where am I going wrong?

```
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'paper') ||
  (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'shotgun') ||
  (playerSelection == 'shotgun' && computerSelection == 'rock') {
  console.log(`Sorry! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`);}
}
```

Comment: You're missing the `if` parentheses – `if ( (playerSelectio ... ion == 'rock') ) { ...`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're missing a parentheses on the **if** statement.

```
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    if ((playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'paper') ||
        (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'shotgun') ||
        (playerSelection == 'shotgun' && computerSelection == 'rock')) {
        console.log(`Sorry! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`);
    }
}
```